# Generic sorting function

Tags: typescript, generic-programming

I am trying to make the material UI sorting function into a generic typed. So that I can use it with any kind of table. I am stuck at using `stableSort` function, which uses `getSorting` function.

**stableSort:**

```
const getSorting = <K extends keyof any>(
    order: Order,
    orderBy: K,
): (a: { [key in K]: number | string }, b: { [key in K]: number | string }) => number =>
    order === "desc" ? (a, b) => desc(a, b, orderBy) : (a, b) => -desc(a, b, orderBy);
```

**getSorting:**

```
const stableSort = <T>(array: T[], cmp: (a: T, b: T) => number): T[] => {
    const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index] as [T, number]);
    stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
        const order = cmp(a[0], b[0]);
        if (order !== 0) return order;
        return a[1] - b[1];
    });
    return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
};
```

And thats how I am using the functions,

```
interface ITableProps<T> {
    title: string;
    rows: T[];
    defaultOrderBy: keyof T;
    order: Order;
}

const SomeTable = <T>(props: ITableProps<T>) => {
    const rowsPerPage = 10;
    const page = 0;

    const handleRequestSort = <T>(property: keyof T): void => {
        const isDesc = props.defaultOrderBy === property && props.order === "desc";
    };

    const sortingFunction = getSorting<keyof T>(props.order, props.defaultOrderBy);

    const temp = stableSort<T>(props.rows, sortingFunction)
                    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                    .map((row, index) => createTableRow(row, index))
}
```

**Couple of problems I am facing,**

1. I dont understand why it thinks `props.defaultOrderBy === property` will always be `false`. I know that both are `keyof T`, but thats a generic type, and their values will not be the same. [Small contained replication of this problem in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUD2BbCBhHAB0xAnAAUpNCBnAHgBUA+ZAbwFgAoZH5GYKDTAA1OABsArhABcyANYQAnphjIGAbi69kNCAhIATUZJnylKtZs4BfLl30ghyLLgLZipcMgC8yRkwAKQipaWQwcfCISMjBKanpmAEpZADdMYAMfFg5uXgcnGgiAMQkQBDBgEh8-ZiCQ6DBFWQVlVQZk5AAjTEwxCDgQLLYtbV4oCDAJKEHg+IA6fkERcSkfb19ZwgbFK21rKxGefLBkSHdqwtwSsoqSOvndByMViESrayA)
2. I have a compilation error when calling `stableSort` function. (**Solved**, check my answer below)

[Here is the playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=1&pln=53&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgEwnKBeKAiAhgZwMYZQA+mS+GA3ALABQteA9gHY7BRl5pQA8AKgHwAKLAC4ovADRQARmMlQGiZACEQYgNYQQDAGbiAlGICMxKAFoTJAAxp+UAN60ozqAEs9g6QG1FSOKoBdHigsHyV-EAD9BycXOLgIYABXOCZzI2oaOIBfWOd3KE8wv0CoO1DfFUjoxyy4lwTk1KgMvKhcuudGlLSrTOzM+mZWKFYsaQAbCABlRTZ0PiEsODgsNXEvAKk8AFswMWE5KVkDWygmJJ3pZEMNoNQ7WrjGFjYx6VcJ1wAvCAReAAWrhwXGWqxAADodlgwIJBBAJlJXEwkAAPaIPKBeBFIlEQVFBXBY+QXK7IKKZOLvT4-P6A4EQnBzOFYY4Yx5tZ7DNiVFDoXaw0JWLYyLzC-SU+r5Dy8qAAQlQ6Cs0W6zV5kqlqrSoSMQTMot1GvaEraWtGwHGNN+-yBOChMLhCPZUARYoptAGtCGrygAHNErM4MBkb6uNwANIu1HACAokGabR6LBMEBCNq8sTwPwSdPhVRicM5mi3Q4OLEJtxpcMBMSk64oEisOAh9rHMT2ctaStQau1y710xNlvZZ115C2XN+NCK0gQchQAD8hVZMmdHGExykvNU0QOK+kzrM6-3W7zIBNdBoLxGeASWBjvHGUwASgwAO5hgSCODvo6VtF9mScC3AAbgwrgIGcTwuNeDBTBCEwML637vriaIXh0tDIjGcA6FgeDQAAko+kwQAACj+YA4IsMSdFAwbAFMYhDkwvpGj+b44HImxGkgeFJBMwBZlUGhaLo4hGhmsDhP0XpXty4hkdMJFTJ+QhgJRXFQMRT7kZpizOtBzjXmwHE4GRyBkVg-pcEYfRtCZUBgNZ0BKoMdGOQCyYIC+EAAI5JHOwCBvMPBfhpDCQEG6wJuJvCgeBkGYkZ9SOcCAAic6cOgEVURCfFYAJQlntOOWUcgoBQAAZFVTmaRCsqKugGAcJQbSepeXI+kyQYhgAYkkTB4MGzBcP6wVzCG3CxXo4X1byUi5XaBVFcJEQXg5CkxnsXDvFMIWLIIS0QmZUg9cGrEDUNI1MPonJSg9ziMl8BFHS5UAAFRQGZFlwFZ-qLe9X0-ZZ70ANTfe+5mg-6d10Y9j32rCKFvmh+LOreED3hAKkQK+b4o2j6Jwx0QA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem one can be resolved this was

```
interface ISomeComponentProps<T> {
    firstValue: keyof T;
    secondValue: keyof T;
}

const SomeComponent = <T>(props: ISomeComponentProps<T>): void => {
    const someFunction = <P>(property: keyof T): boolean => {
        return props.firstValue === property;
    };

    const temp = someFunction(props.secondValue);
}
```

In your previous code you were using `someFunction = <T>(property: keyof T)` That causes typescript to lose its reference to the outer generic `T` since they are the same generic variable. By switching the inside function to `<P>(property: keyof T)` we are saying that the inside is a generic function that must take as its property a keyof the outside function. That is the only way to ensure that there will be overlap is by typing it so that there must be.

You can also tell TS that it may be a key of T but not necessarily by typing it this way

```
const someFunction = <P>(property: keyof T | string): boolean => ...
```

Now you are saying that `P` is either a `keyof` the outside `props` or a string. Obviously you can replace string with whatever other values you might have there.

Comment: Oh I see what I did wrong. I knew its something basic. I liked your first approach and it worked for me. I would not want to use `<P>(property: keyof T | string): boolean =>`, just because if I have to reassign `property` later to another `keyof T` variable, it will complain about `typeof T | string` is not assignable to type `typeof T`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figure out the typing for `2`nd problem. But for now I can use a hacky way to ignore the `1`st problem, and move on. Which is just using `props.defaultOrderBy as string`

[Here is the solution to the 1st problem and ignores the 2nd](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gTgEwnKBeKAiAhgZwMYZQA+mS+GA3ALABQteA9gHY7BRl5pQA8AKgHwAKLAC4ovADRQARmMlQGiZACEQYgNYQQDAGbiAlGICMxKAFoTJAAxp+UAN60ozqAEs9g6QG1FSOKoBdHigsHyV-EAD9BycXOLgIYABXOCZzI2oaOIBfWOd3KE8wv0CoO1DfFUjoxyy4lwTk1KgMvKhcuudGlLSrTOzM+mZWKFYsaQAbCABlRTZ0PiEsODgsNXEvAKk8AFswMWE5KVkDWygmJJ3pZEMNoNQ7WrjGFjYx6VcJ1wAvCAReAAWrhwXGWqxAADodlgwIJBBAJlJXEwkAAPaIPKBeBFIlEQVFBXBY+QXK7IKKZOLvT4-P6A4EQnBzOFYY4Yx5tZ7DNiVFDoXaw0JWLYyLzC-SU+r5Dy8qAAQlQ6Cs0W6zV5kqlqrSoSMQTMot1GvaEraWtGwHGNN+-yBOChMLhCPZUARYoptAGtFo+LAcygLxGAHNErM4MBkYGuItBG1eWJ4H4JLHwqoNFpdOIkzRbodMzI5M7Sdc+fxk340IrSBByFAAPyFVkyZ0cYTHKS81TRA6N6TOswtnvtlMgE10GgBth4BJYYAQXjjKYAJQYAHcowJBHBV0c3HjUWIizcxAA3BiuBBnJ4uAMMKYQiYMQOb1e4tGjjq0ZGzuA6LB4aAAJLzpMEAAApbmAOCLDEnRQOGwBTGIrBwBGRpbiuOByJsRpIL+SQTMACZVGm2h6LwRpxrA4T9F647cuIoHTMBUzrkIYAQZhUBAQuYEcYszpXs4E5QOhOCgcgoFYMGXBGH0bTCWAUnQEqgywcJAJYCiS4QAAjkk1bAKG8w8Bu7EMJAYbrJopEGCeZ4Xpign1MJwIACLVpw6BmZBEK4Vg+GEcOFZeRByCgCEILIRGUAAGQxVA3l2rKiroBgHCUG0npjlyryjHMEYAGJJEweDhswXDBoZ+VMIG0aJRCvJSPVfkBURESjvJ9GznsXDvFMRl1RxEKiVITJhoVxWla4zD6JyUrzc4jJfP+giKdJABUImrmJElKU1SlQJtoniXAknSQA1FtGEnWdECzbBC0LfasLPiur74s6U4QDOc48cuK6ve96L3R0QA)

If someone has a better solution, please do share it with me.